# JAVA - creating an Iterator for tree data structure, that implements iterator, and gets Head node

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator

I am implementing a binary tree. I created an Iterator class for the tree that implements iterator but i must give it the tree for the constructor:

```
    public class AvlIterator implements Iterable<Integer>{
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator(AvlTree avlTree){
    //here i construct the iterator class, with the avlTree inside.
    }
}
```

But the interface doesn't get any object in its constructor. It tells me to add this signature:

```
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator();
```

So what is wrong with my implementation? On one hand i need the tree object for doing my operations, on the other hand Java is "Telling me" that i am not doing things properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the `AvlIterator` an inner class of your `AvlTree` class, it will have access to the `AvlTree` instance, and you won't have to pass anything to the `iterator()` method. This way you can implement the method required by the `Iterable` interface.

Actually, it would make more sense if `AvlTree` itself implements `Iterable<Integer>`. `AvlIterator` would implement `Iterator<Integer>`.

```
public class AvlTree implements Iterable<Integer>
{

    ...
    class AvlIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
    {
        ... here you have access to the properties of the enclosing AvlTree instance ...
    }
    ...

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator()
    {
        return new AvlIterator ();
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Or better use an anonymous class within the method iterator() that extends Iterator<Integer> and return that. And AvlTree must extend Iterable<Integer>

Comment: This is how most iterators are implemented in the JVM so it is probably the right way to go.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle - Are you saying that anonymous classes is the preferred method or are inner classes the preferred method?

Comment: Thanks so much! that really is what i needed.

Comment: @user3493289 Inner classes. Your proposition is also a clean way to implement this inner class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "What is wrong with my implementation", `Iterable<T>` interface has one method called `Iterator<T> iterator()` which has to be implemented by the class which implements that interface. If you see the method signature, it doesn't take any argument. So, when you implement a method with an argument, you are effectively NOT overriding this method, but adding another overloaded method. So, the compiler complains that you have to implement the method.

This is why, it is always recommended to annotate with `@Override` to any method which you 'think' you are overriding. This will catch if the method signature doesn't match the method you are trying to override.

For example, many might do the mistake of overriding `equals` method with the type they are overriding for, instead of `Object`, which is effectively NOT overriding. Without `@Override`, everything with compile, but it can create bizarre bugs if that type of objects are used in Collection framework or even when using equals methods.

```
public boolean equals(Employee employee) {
    //amazing logic to find equality
}
```

is a wrong implementation and can escape compiler without `@Override` annotation.